# Remove certain files form PR change set

Tags: github-actions

I'm using jitterbit/get-changed-files as part of my workflow in GitHub. I'm taking this changeset and passing it through different tests. However, sometimes I get a PR in which the change set includes files I don't want to be tested. For example, anything in the src/third_party directory. Is there a way to remove this directory from the changeset?

The workflow runs on a self-hosted Windows machine.

```
name: Testing Workflow

on:
  pull_request

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest 
    steps:
      uses: actions/checkout@v2 
       
       - id: changeset
         name: Get PR Changeset 
         uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1

      - id: filtered-changeset
        name: Filter the Changeset
        run: |
          # HOW DO I DO THIS??
```

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, I forked that action so that I could filter the contents out of the resulting changed file list.

See: https://github.com/halaslabs/get-changed-files.

You should be able to achieve what you are looking for with the path-filters input option.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest 
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Get Changed Files
        id: changeset
        uses: halaslabs/get-changed-files@v2
        with:
          path-filters: src/third_party/**
```

Comment: I'm testing this out, and it seems that the "path-filters" options includes the directory, while I want it excluded.

Comment: @user Feel free to open an issue on the repo and I can take a look.